# Basic Pig Latin Translator returning a NoMethodError

Tags: arrays, ruby, nomethoderror

What I've got here gives me the solution I'm looking for but I get a NoMethodError for the slice method when I run it.

```
def pig_it(text)
  b4pig = text.split(" ")
  l1 = b4pig[0].slice(0,1)
  l2 = b4pig[1].slice(0,1)
  l3 = b4pig[2].slice(0,1)
  l4 = b4pig[3].slice(0,1)
  
  done = b4pig[0].delete(l1)+l1+"ay " + b4pig[1].delete(l2)+l2+"ay " + b4pig[2].delete(l3)+l3+"ay " + b4pig[3].delete(l4)+l4+"ay"
  return done
  
end
```

All the program needs to do is convert the first phrase to the second phrase

('Pig latin is cool'),'igPay atinlay siay oolcay')
('This is my string'),'hisTay siay ymay tringsay')

Comment: I see no error when the string contains four words. I suspect you got the error when testing with a string containing fewer than four words. If the string contained three words, for example,  `b4pig[3]` would return `nil`, so `nil.slice(0,1)` would generate a `NoMethodError` since `nil` does not have a method `slice`. Incidentally, when reporting that there was an exception include the entire message and the line in which the error occurred. In general, pay close attention to error messages; often they will pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested one possible reason for the exception in a comment on the question, but you have not given enough information for readers to provide a definitive explanation.

---

I would like to suggest an alternative construction of your method that has three advantages:

- the argument, a string, may contain any number of words;
- punctuation is permitted; and
- whitespace is preserved (e.g, tabs, line terminators, extra spaces)

The method is as follows.

```
def pig_it(text)
  text.gsub(/[a-z]+/i) { |word| format("%s%sya", word[1..], word[0] }
end
```

Let's try it.

```
pig_it "Baa, baa black sheep\nHave you any wool?"
  #=> "aaBya, aabya lackbya heepsya\naveHya ouyya nyaya oolwya?"
```

---

See [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) and [Kernel#format](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format).

`/[a-z]+/i` is a *regular expression*. `[a-z]` is a *character class*. It matches exactly one character in the character class. The character class contains all lower case letters of the alphabet. `[a-z]+` matches one or more lower-case letters. The `i` following `/` means the expression is *case insensitive*, meaning the expression matches one or more letters, each letter being lower or upper case. It follows that whitespace and punctuation are not matched.

The block (`{ |word| .... }`) contains the *block variable* `word` which holds each match of the regular expression. In the example, `word` will in turn hold "Baa", "baa", "black" and so on.

Suppose `word` holds "black", then

```
word[0]   #=> "b"
word[1..] #=> "lack"

format("%s%sya", word[1..], word[0])
  #=> format("%s%sya", "lack", "b")
  #=> "lackbya"
```

I kept your method name because I do not think it can be improved upon.